# Javascript : Replace Event Listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am listening to an event and want to call different methods. For example, I am listening to animation end event and the code is something like this:

```
this.inAnimationCallback = function() {
    console.log('In');
    _this.elem.className = _this.settings.className;
};
this.outAnimationCallback = function() {
    console.log('Out');
    _this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(_this.elem);
};

this.elem.addEventListener(animationEvent, this.inAnimationCallback);

setTimeout(function() {
    _this.elem.addEventListener(animationEvent, _this.outAnimationCallback);
    // Call some animation here.
}, 3000);
```

What happens here is that instead of replacing the method attached to the event, JS adds the method and when animation ends, both methods are called. Console looks like this:

```
(2) In
Out
```

Comment: Well you have to call `removeEventListener` with the other method…

Comment: @Bergi It works! Fk, yeah. I had the idea of `removeEventListener` but I did something like: `this.elem.removeEventListener(animationEvent);`. It didn't work but now calling it by passing the method I want to remove results in proper working. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi Would you like to add answer or should I remove the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm writing this answer for those like me, who is just started learning JS. And this thread came up first in google to "js replace event listener"..
Although, I am **not** disagreeing with the answers to use `removeEventListener()`, but mozilla **[warns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)** that this function is **not** always successful. So use it with **care**. not willing to go that road i have found two other ways to do it.

1. Use something like **[GlobalEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers)**  which is simple as **`target.onclick = functionRef;`**. [Mozilla even warns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):

   > **Only one onclick handler can be assigned to an object at a time.**
2. **Within listener** function add **external** function call to **action** function, and then replace **reference** to **another external action** function. For example this code will call `firstAction()`, then `seconAction()`, then first again...:

   ```js
       const buttonOne = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
       buttonOne.addEventListener('click', listenerFunction);

       let doAction = firstAction; //assigning doAction to firstAction

       function listenerFunction() {
           doAction(); //external function call
       }
       function firstAction() {
           doAction = secondAction; //assigning doAction to secondAction
           console.log('first action clicked');
       }
       function secondAction() {
           doAction = firstAction; //assigning doAction to firstAction
           console.log('second action clicked');
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <button type="button" id="buttonOne" name="button">button1</button>
   ```

I wrote this answer to broaden solution scope: would have saved at least 6 hours of my time. If I had this in the first place...

Comment: I have reviewed your answer and found it to be good enough to be accepted. Nice explanation with references!

Comment: thank you for compliment. i just hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove the event listener before adding the new one :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    _this.elem.removeEventListener(animationEvent, _this.inAnimationCallback);
    _this.elem.addEventListener(animationEvent, _this.outAnimationCallback);
    // Call some animation here.
}, 3000);
```